# Lasclip produces overlap with non-overlapping shapefiles

Tags: r, lidar, las, lidr

Using a set of non-overlapping polygons (sf object) to clip a `LAScatalog` or `LAS` object creates an overlapping set of `LAS` files. I think the overlap is due to the use of the bounding box of the shapes rather than the shape itself but I'm not sure. Are the resulting las files really overlapping? Or are they just appearing as such due to the use of the bounding box?

- clip shape:

```
> wp_shape
Simple feature collection with 25 features and 5 fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 563164.3 ymin: 4868599 xmax: 563346 ymax: 4868781
epsg (SRID):    26918
proj4string:    +proj=utm +zone=18 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
First 10 features:
   id comp_id    area subplot_id PLOT_ID                       geometry
1   1      20 335.285         12   20_12 POLYGON ((563307.7 4868739,...
2   2      20 335.021          6    20_6 POLYGON ((563346 4868725, 5...
3   3      20 353.954         11   20_11 POLYGON ((563299.2 4868717,...
4   4      20 358.526          5    20_5 POLYGON ((563321.1 4868710,...
5   5      20 342.092          4    20_4 POLYGON ((563313.6 4868688,...
6   6      20 346.649          3    20_3 POLYGON ((563304.9 4868666,...
7   7      20 340.926          2    20_2 POLYGON ((563297.7 4868644,...
8   8      20 338.967          1    20_1 POLYGON ((563289.8 4868622,...
9   9      20 366.296         10   20_10 POLYGON ((563291.6 4868696,...
10 10      20 366.606          9    20_9 POLYGON ((563283.4 4868675,...
> plot(wp_shape$geometry)
```

[image]

- `LAScatalog` and clip shape overlay: 
  [image]
- resulting clipped `LAS` files:

```
> clipped_ctg <- readLAScatalog("~/Downloads/wp_plots/")
# Be careful, some tiles seem to overlap each other. lidR may return incorrect outputs with edge artifacts when processing this catalog.
> lidR::is.overlapping(clipped_ctg)
# [1] TRUE
> plot(clipped_ctg)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. When reading a collection of files only the header is read and thus what you are seeing is the bounding box of the files. But the actual point cloud is what you are expecting.

Consequently you are seeing overlapping files and `is.overlapping()` is also seeing overlapping files because there is not way to know the actual content of the files without reading them. It is a false positive by design.

When processing such kind of catalog made of independent files it is important to set the good options. You must process with a buffer of 0 and by file:

```r
opt_chunk_size(ctg) <- 0
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg) <- 0
```

Otherwise buffer will expend on other files loading two disjoint and independent areas. Also because some functions do not work if `buffer = 0` such as `grid_terrain()` to guarantee a strict wall-to-wall output you can disable such guaranties.

```r
opt_wall_to_wall(ctg) <- FALSE
```

From v3.0.0 an option `opt_independent_files(ctg) <- TRUE` will be available to simplify the procedure.

You can also simply write your own `for` loop.

Comment: is it possible to see a list of opt_* settings in the current environment?

Comment: Please ask a question.